# How to turn Google chrome into firefox clone

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, clone

Ok I'm addicted to firefox, BUT I cannot be blind: chrome way to handle webpages (pre-loading, rendering and other features) is great.

I was thinking to use this browser, however it's quite hard without something about the interface which is NECESSARY:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Images/firefox.png

Here you can see my interface, I really need something to handle bookmarks on a left pane (history too), I do something similar in visual studio and I want preserve it.

Second needed thing is the right input bar where I can choose a search engine, i use it for wordreference, youtube and wikipedia, while the address bar is used for google.

Third, I don't need live bookmarks because I notices I put them all in a directory ("Notizie"), so something that will contain all rss feed is ok, but should be always visible.

A way to throttle bandwith is necessary.

ADBlock is necessary and that's all.

Optional things:

- I've heared about a plugin to search through an image (instead of text), it was for firefox... does it exist for chrome too?
- Something to take a "screenshot" of a whole webpage (even if is scrollable)
- Sound when download is completed (isn't it already there?)
- Flagfox (show a flag about where the website comes from)
- Some addon to take all urls from a text
- Double click on a link not "linked" (not in  tag) to open in as it was a link

Some suggestion guys?

Comment: I highly doubt you will get it configured the way you like it the Chromium framework is pretty minimalistic and that's the reason why I don't use it.. cant get the layout I like :\. If you end up sticking with Firefox give the Ubiquity add-on a shot instead of using that search bar to switch search engines.

Comment: You won't be able to make all these changes without heavily modifying Chrome's source code.  It's simply not able to do this.  You can get some of the speed optimizations mentioned with the [FasterFox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/RsccmanFasterfox/) for Firefox, however.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion guys...
As I thought, I can't live without firefox

Luckily with ssd is quite istant-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really need something to handle
>   bookmarks on a left pane (history
>   too), I do something similar in visual
>   studio and I want preserve it.
>
> Second needed thing is the right input
>   bar where I can choose a search
>   engine, i use it for wordreference,
>   youtube and wikipedia, while the
>   address bar is used for google.

No, this is not possible.

> I've heared about a plugin to search through an image (instead of text), it was for firefox... does it exist for chrome too?

[TinEye](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/haebnnbpedcbhciplfhjjkbafijpncjl)

> Something to take a "screenshot" of a whole webpage (even if is scrollable)

[Explain And Send Screenshots](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdddabjhelpilpnpgondfmehhcplpiin)

> Double click on a link not "linked" (not in tag) to open in as it was a link

Right click, Go to.. or [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aegfbpchoheaflicfmggkmlmcccpjpgd)

> Flagfox..

[ChromeFlags](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jhejngphiacapbgllhagbpdkkdieeaej)