# Can I set a hotkey to "click" on an icon in the plugin bar?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, hotkeys

I would like to use chrome instead of firefox because of his synching mechanism, which in firefox is quite faulty (only bookmarks are imported, a big problem 'cos I need extensions too).

I managed to make chrome really similar to firefox with plugins and things like that (I asked it in my previous question: [How to turn Google chrome into firefox clone](https://superuser.com/questions/261568/how-to-turn-google-chrome-into-firefox-clone) ).

However I'm missing an important thing: I need to bind in some way (changing the source code of the plugin or using anything else) CTRL + B to "click" to an icon in the plugin bar (basically I have to show the dialog that pops up when you click on that icon).

How to do it? I can write javascript/html/css code (but I would like to avoid to reimplement the whole plugin), any suggestion?

Here is a screenshot of the icon that I need to click:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Images/Bookmarks.png]

P.S.

The plugin is [Neat Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nnancliccjabjjmipbpjkfbijifaainp).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't double post your questions, pick the right side that fits your question the most. As you've got an answer on Stack Overflow it didn't had any use posting it at Super User, it's off-topic here anyway...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Matchu stated on the [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466631/google-chrome-set-a-hotkey-to-click-over-an-icon-in-the-plugin-bar-a-plugin-a), this is not doable.

Comment: This is indeed possible on Windows using AutoHotkey. I will post a solution later today. :)

Comment: I know autohotkey but this is a software that is external to google chrome. I want something internal to the browser itself, a script or something similar, as stated in the question.